# Range in Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

i want get the range from cell A1 to end of the cell which contains the data only.

I tried this few way still failed.

Example:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Address

Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
```

regards,
YY

Comment: Find the last row using [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) and then construct your range :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Address).Select
```